# What is the sum of integers between 1 and 200 inclusive that are divisible by both 4 and 5?

Tags: summation

What is the sum of integers between 1 and 200 inclusive that are divisible by both 4 and 5?

Now I attempt the question of taking the integers to be divisible by 20(LCM of 4 and 5) and get the number of terms as 10 and the sum as 1100. Is it the right approach, experts?

Q-2 Had the same question been " What is the sum of integers between 1 and 200 inclusive that are divisible by either 4 or 5? Is this the right approach?
A- Sum of terms div by 4+ Sum of terms div by 5 - Sum of terms div by 20(LCM of 4 and 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right both times. For Q2 we get $4\cdot 1275+5\cdot820-1100=5100+4100-1100=8100$